# Can I keep a tkinter window open while using stored variables?

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar, global-variables, jupyter

In a Jupyter notebook, I use tkinter to collect user input so other code can generate an output file. I have created a submit button to store the variables, but I must close the tkinter window before the rest of the code is able to use them and run to the output.

I would like to be able to run all the way to the output file, then enter new inputs without closing and restarting. How can I keep the tkinter window open the whole time?

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd

class MyWindow:
    def __init__(self, win):
        self.lbl=Label(win, text="Tool")
        self.lbl1=Label(win, text='ndays')
        self.lbl2=Label(win, text='Date 1')

        self.t1=Entry()
        self.t2=Entry()

        self.lbl.place(x=150, y=10)

        self.lbl1.place(x=50, y=50)
        self.t1.place(x=150, y=50)

        self.lbl2.place(x=50, y=90)
        self.t2.place(x=150, y=90)    
        self.b1=Button(win, text='Submit', command=self.submit)

        self.b2=Button(win, text='Refresh')
        self.b2.bind('<Button-1>', self.refresh)

        self.b1.place(x=150, y=260)
        self.b2.place(x=270, y=260)

    def submit(self):
        global ndays, screen

        ndays=self.t1.get()
        screen=self.t2.get()

    #in case of refresh
    def refresh(self, event):
        self.t1.delete(0, 'end')
        self.t2.delete(0, 'end')

window=Tk()
mywin=MyWindow(window)
window.title("Tool")
window.geometry("400x400+10+10")
window.mainloop()
```

I cannot access the name and screen date variables without exiting the tkinter window. I'd like to be able to refresh the variables and run it again to the output without having to close the window.

The code below are the next steps I'll be running to create a custom calendar.

```
screen = datetime.datetime.strptime(screen, '%m/%d/%y').date()

# find the of the number of days backwards.
ndays=int(ndays)
thirty_back = screen + relativedelta(days=-ndays - 1)

delta1 = screen - thirty_back

# Empty lists to loop into
date_list = []  # dates
day_counter_thing = []
day_o_week = []  # real day of week
counter = []  # list for the days used

day_count = -1  # starts at -1 so that screen day can be 0

for i in range(delta1.days):
    day = screen - timedelta(days=i)  # know where to start the tlfb

    date_list.append(day)  # list of dates in the loop
    day_count = day_count + 1  # add a count for each day in the loop
    counter.append(day_count)  # keep a list of all the day counts

    day_o_week.append(day.strftime("%A"))  # add the real day of the week
    name = day.weekday()  # name of day by index of day in week
    day_counter_thing.append(name)  # keep the list
max_day = max(counter)  # gives you reference so that you can swap the counter after screen

# put the values from the loops into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date_list, "Day": day_o_week, "Counter": day_counter_thing, "TLFB_Day": counter})
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to quit the window before using the values? There's no requirement that says you have to do that.

Comment: I am using jupyter and if I attempt to use the variable in a kernel below it only displays  * on the side and will not run.

Comment: I think using jupyter is an important detail that you left out of your question.

Comment: My bad! I've tried using IDLE too now though. When I run this code though IDLE in a .py file, I also have the same issue of needing to quit the window before the variables can be used elsewhere. What would be a next step?

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't use it before destroying the window. Your `submit` function can access the variables before the window is destroyed. In fact, it _can't_ access the variables after its destroyed.

Comment: Haha! Well I'm not sure either. When I run this code, the window appears, I enter information and click submit, but need to exit the window before a variable will print. This issue occurs in PyCharm as well, so I think it is an issue with this code. Is there a better way to store these variables?

Comment: _"I enter information and click submit, but need to exit the window before a variable will print. "_ - frankly, I don't see why you would ever see anything printed - the `submit` function gets the value but never prints it.

Comment: print was only an example-- when I try to use the variable in any of the code I've written outside of the main loop, it will not run and my final output file will not be created until I exit the window.

Comment: Your example code needs to show how you are attempting to use the variables. _outside of the main loop_ is a critical detail that you've left out. In the normal case the program exits after mainloop exits.

Comment: If the variables won't even print outside of the main loop, I don't see how they could be used in other parts of code. I didn't want to post too much but now I see how it would be helpful. I'll post above.

Comment: They can be used in other parts of the code simply because they exist. Why would tkinter allow you to create variables that you can't use? Typically, mainloop doesn't exit until the window has been destroyed. Once the main window has been destroyed you can no longer access widgets or the StringVars.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make sense. What would you suggest?

Comment: The global statement is `global name, screen`.  The function sets screen to `t2.get()` but sets ndays to `t1.get()`. ndays isn't a global variable, name is.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the edit. I have corrected the global variable issue.  Now that I have also added ndays=0 and screen=0 to outside the class, but it does not seem to function yet.

Comment: The initialising the variables before the class definition was wrong.  I'd changed the names in the class and not changed the global statement.  That's why I deleted the comment.  Does it work now?  I can't reproduce the problem on myPC.  The two variables are visible.

Comment: When I run it in jupyter and attempt to print the variables outside the main loop, the kernals display [*] until I close the tkinter window. In pycharm, the variables and df won't display until after I've closed the tkinter window also. If it works on a PC I'm hopeful that when I switch to a different computer it might work out the way I'm hoping. Any other suggestions? Thank you for your comments!

Comment: Once `mainloop()` is called any other code not in a callback function won't run unless it's running in a different thread.  The responses here have been assuming 'outside the mainloop' meant 'after the loop had stopped running'.  If you add print statements in submit you'll see the state of the variables as the submit button is clicked.  Code not called by events on your tkinter objects won't run until mainloop finishes.

Comment: Ok thank you for bearing with me. It isn't my intention to be imprecise but we're definitely at different skill levels here. I would like to be able to run from input all the way to the output file, then enter new inputs without closing the window and restarting. What do I need to change to keep the tkinter window open the whole time?

Comment: It probably needs a new question. I don't use jupyter and I don't know whether a tkinter app can output to a jupyter sheet without closing. You could put your calendar code into a function `calendar( end_date, days )` and run it in jupyter without any tkinter action.

Comment: Ok thank you. I would like the tkinter action though because this is meant to be a UI for people without any coding experience, who would not want to go into any areas outside of the input window. It doesn't necessarily have to run in Jupyter-- I've tried VSC now too and the same issue arises. So I will repost. How should I phrase the question so that people understand what I mean?

Comment: Do the users need to see the results or do they need to use the dataframe in what they do?  Can the answer posted below help clarify what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This code prints the data frame into the terminal once submit is clicked on the window.  As long as the window is not closed mainloop will be running and it won't be possible to run any other code.

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd

class MyWindow:
    def __init__(self, win):
        self.lbl=Label(win, text="Tool")
        self.lbl1=Label(win, text='ndays')
        self.lbl2=Label(win, text='Date 1')

        self.t1=Entry()
        self.t2=Entry()

        self.lbl.place(x=150, y=10)

        self.lbl1.place(x=50, y=50)
        self.t1.place(x=150, y=50)

        self.lbl2.place(x=50, y=90)
        self.t2.place(x=150, y=90)    
        self.b1=Button(win, text='Submit', command=self.submit)

        self.b2=Button(win, text='Refresh')
        self.b2.bind('<Button-1>', self.refresh)

        self.b1.place(x=150, y=260)
        self.b2.place(x=270, y=260)

    def calendar( self, screen, ndays ):
        # find the of the number of days backwards.

        screen = datetime.datetime.strptime(screen, '%m/%d/%y').date()
        ndays=int(ndays)
        thirty_back = screen + relativedelta(days=-ndays - 1)

        delta1 = screen - thirty_back

        # Empty lists to loop into
        date_list = []  # dates
        day_counter_thing = []
        day_o_week = []  # real day of week
        counter = []  # list for the days used

        day_count = -1  # starts at -1 so that screen day can be 0

        for i in range(delta1.days):
            day = screen - timedelta(days=i)  # know where to start the tlfb

            date_list.append(day)  # list of dates in the loop
            day_count = day_count + 1  # add a count for each day in the loop
            counter.append(day_count)  # keep a list of all the day counts

            day_o_week.append(day.strftime("%A"))  # add the real day of the week
            name = day.weekday()  # name of day by index of day in week
            day_counter_thing.append(name)  # keep the list
        max_day = max(counter)  # gives you reference so that you can swap the counter after screen

        # put the values from the loops into a dataframe
        return pd.DataFrame({'Date': date_list, "Day": day_o_week, "Counter": day_counter_thing, "TLFB_Day": counter})

    def submit(self):
        print( self.calendar( self.t2.get(), self.t1.get()) )

    #in case of refresh
    def refresh(self, event):
        self.t1.delete(0, 'end')
        self.t2.delete(0, 'end')

window=Tk()
mywin=MyWindow(window)
window.title("Tool")
window.geometry("400x400+10+10")
window.mainloop()
```

An alternative would be to show the results in the window itself, instead of printing them, in a text object or series of Labels.

Comment: Ok I'm learning a lot about tkinter from this. Thank you for the start, but I think I needed to clarify earlier that I have much more code later in my program to format and clean the dataframe and then to export it to an xlsx file. To me it looks like it could be done within the def submit button, but I hesitate to do it as I was hoping to have more clear cut chunks of code that served different functions (GUI, date dataframe creation, formatting, export) for my own reference later on. I'm still pretty new to this-- would Threading in some way be appropriate here?

Comment: My guess is your best solution is to process the data in the `submit` method.  Ii's possible to write sets of functions or objects for dataframe creation, formatting and writing to excel outside the `mywindow` class and call them from within it.  This lets you keep the code for the activities separated but call from one point.  The main point to remember is that GUI interfaces act and react to events ( like button clicks ).  Making them work in the background as well is a lot more difficult and often unnecessary.

Comment: I moved it all under the submit method and it works. Thank you for your comments!